# Facebook Graph / FQL - is there a way to bring back or move up my old post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a pretty strange requirement in front of me. I am able to pull out data from facebook Graph and do things around it without a doubt. However, out of the feeds/posts I have (I pulled from me/feed/), I can see some of the feeds are an year old or more. Is there a way by which I can bring up or move up any old post?

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones

Comment: I don't understand your question, the API can return any post back to 2007 (possibly earlier, i wasn't on facebook before 2007 though) as far as I know

Comment: No brother, I mean, Facebook or Graph API can return a post info, but is it possible to bring up or move up my old post? Probably update the priority or something of the post and it should start appearing again at the top, among my feeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you **cannot** edit the date of a post, or otherwise 'bump' it to the top of your Timeline via the API

Comment: how do i 'bump' the post to the top of my timeline via api? is it still possible? Thanks!

Comment: Let me highlight the 'cannot' in my post, it may not have been clear